# Why is it saying that a name of something is undefined even though it is a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, error-handling

```
people = {"a":0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0}

def changes(option):
    if option == 1:
        person = input("Who would you like to add points to? ")
        print(person)
        amount = input("How many points would you like to add to " + str(person) + "?")
        people[person] += amount
        print("SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED: " + person + " now has " + str(people.person) + " points")
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: And show what you entered to the prompts.

Comment: `amount` is a string, you can't add it to a number.

Comment: `person` is a string, you don't need to use `str(person)`'

Comment: `people.person` should be `people[person]`

Comment: If `amount` is supposed to be a number - and it is, convert it: `amount = int(input(...))`. Also, you should have a look at [string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-f-string-literal) rather than rely on concatenating pieces of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `str(people.person)` with `people[person]`
Because you are trying to access `people['person']` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

*person* is not a key, It's a variable that holds the key.

**This will work:**

```
people = {"a":0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0}

def changes(option):
    if option == 1:
        person = input("Who would you like to add points to? ")
        print(person)
        amount = int(input("How many points would you like to add to " + str(person) + "?"))
        people[person] +=   amount
        print("SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED: " + person + " now has " + str(people[person]) + " points")
 
        
changes(1)
```